# Empty content-type while downloading file with Jersey client

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey

I'm trying to download a file with the Jersey client.
I'm requesting an API, and I don't have API source code.
For one URL, the API returns an empty "Content-Type" header (the header is present but empty).
Jersey does not like this:

> Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: ""

I'd like to keep the Jersey client if possible

- Is an API supposed to return an empty content-type?
- Is there any header I can add to my request that may solve the problem? I tried content-type and accept without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Content-Type header manually *after* you receive the response.

```
Response res = target.request().get();
res.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octect-stream");
InputStream file = res.readEntity(InputStream.class);
```

Comment: Does not answer to my question "is an API supposed to return an empty content-type", but solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: A well-designed one is not supposed to